# Open a WPF from a click button in my Outlook addin

Tags: c#, wpf, outlook, add-in, outlook-addin

I have a `BarButton` inside a `MenuBar` I created as an AddIn for Microsoft Outlook.
Now I need to open my WPF application if I click the button. I've also already developed the WPF application.

My goal is to join them, but I'm missing the part to launch the WPF when the button is clicked.

This is my button, and I need to complete my `_HandlerUserSettings` function:

```
var objUserButton = (Office.CommandBarButton)objTfMenuBar.Controls.Add(Office.MsoControlType.msoControlButton, missing, missing, missing, true);
objUserButton.Click += new Office._CommandBarButtonEvents_ClickEventHandler(_HandlerUserSettings);
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the button click event handler, create a process to start your application

```
string myWpfAppPath = "C:\somepath\someapp.exe";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(myWpfAppPath);
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically it was something easy like this:

```
var windowUserSettings = new WpfUserSettings();
windowUserSettings.Show();
```

where the WpfUserSettings class is the WPF class.